# Congruence and similarity of matrices/ geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$ we can tell if those two matrices are congruent, similar, or neither.  Similarly given two figures in Euclidean geometry we can tell if they are congruent, similar, or neither.

Is there a relationship between these two ideas (congruence/ similarity for matrices and congruence/ similarity for geometric figures) that justifies the use of the same names?